Proving that the successor is injective
I'm trying to prove that the successor of X, defined as
\begin{equation}
S(X) = X \, \cup \, \{ X \}
\end{equation}
is "injective" (if $X \neq Y \implies S(X) \neq S(Y)$). In this forum I have read other well-done proofs about this fact, but I'm trying to prove this using the hint that the book I'm currently using to study at a deeper level Analysis. My book suggests to start from $X \neq Y \wedge S(X) = S(Y)$ and to use the Axiom of Regularity with the set $A = \{ X, Y \}$.
Note: as other have pointed me out and for the sake of future readers, $S$ is not strictly a function to be precise, rather a "notation" to indicate the set defined as shown at the start of the question. So I want to demonstrate that $X \neq Y \implies S(X) \neq S(Y)$ which is a statement very similar to the definition of injective function (and that is why I have said that I wanted to prove that $S$ is injective but, logically speaking, is wrong because $S$ is not a function).
My attempt: $X \in S(X)$ because $S(X) = X \, \cup \, \{ X \}$. But $S(X) = S(Y)$ then $X \in S(Y) \implies X \in \{ Y, \{ Y \} \}$. We know by hypothesis that $X \neq Y$ so it must be that $X = \{ Y \}$. Similarly we can obtain that $Y = \{ X \}$. We now observe that $\forall a \in A, \nexists y \in A : (y \in A) \wedge (y \, \cap A = \emptyset)$: in fact we see that $X \in A$ and $X \, \cap A = \{ Y \}$ and, similarly, for $Y$ we see that $Y \in A$ and $Y \, \cap \, A = \{ X \}$. This is a contradiction of the axiom of regularity, that can be expressed as
$$
\forall A \exists y: ((y \in A) \wedge (y \, \cap \, A) = \emptyset)
$$
I'm not too sure about my "proof": I'm not conviced in the statement $X = \{ Y \}$ and the use of the axiom of regularity in the way I used it above. Sorry if this question will probably sounds simple and for some English mistakes I could have written (it's not my native language)

$S(Y)\neq {Y,{Y}}.$ So you can't conclude the $X\in {Y,{Y}}.$

Note that $X\cap A={Y}$ not $X\cap A=Y$.

@ThomasAndrews I don't understand why $S(Y) \neq { Y , { Y } }$: the successor of $Y$ is defined as $S(Y) = Y \cup { Y }$, so why it is not $S(Y) = {Y, { Y }}$?

@Lucenaposition ah, thank you: I'll correct the error as soon as possible

Err..., what is the definition domain of your function?

@SergeBallesta S goes from the class of all sets to the class of all sets, no?

@SergeBallesta Strictly speaking $S$ is not a function, but when developing the basic set theory it's very usual to write $S(X)$ (which strictly speaking will be wrong) to abbreviate $X \cup {X}$ and think it as a "function". To prove that this "function" is "injective" is then translated into proving that for all sets, $X\cup {X}=Y\cup {Y}$ implies $X=Y$, if you want to be completely purist...

$S(Y) \ne {Y,{Y}}$. Take, for example, $Y={a,b}$. Then $S(Y) = Y \cup {Y} = {a,b}\cup{{a,b}} = {a,b,{a,b}}$. Instead, the expression you're writing is ${Y,{Y}} = {{a,b},{{a,b}}}$

Maybe I found another way without using the wrong statement I wrote: if $X \in S(X) \implies X \in S(Y) \implies X \in (Y \cup { Y }$) but that implies that $(X \in Y) , \vee , (X \in { Y })$. We observe that by one of the various consequences of the axiom of pairing we have that if$x \in {y} \implies x = y$ but, for hypothesis, we exclude that. So it must means that $X \in Y$ and, similarly, we can do the same for $Y$ and conclude that $Y \in X$. But that is a contradiction of the Axiom of Regularity because $X, Y \in A$ and $X \cap A = { Y }$, $Y \cap A = { X }$

@jjagmath: I can understand what you say. I just think that, for the sake of future readers, OP could have add a line explaining that S could not be a true function...

$A\cup B\neq {A,B},$ which is what you seem to be suggesting. If $A={1,2,3}$ and $B={1,4},$ then $A\cup B={1,2,3,4}$ and ${A,B}={{1,2,3},{1,4}}.$ @Fr4ncim

@Fr4nci Yes, your most recent comment has the right idea.

Initial remark:
Speaking of function and injection is kind of a language abuse. A function is expected to be defined on a set. As the set of all sets is known not to exist, $S$ has no definition domain and because of that cannot be a true function. That being said nothing is bad is defining it as a notation...
So the question boils down to proving that if 2 sets $X$ and $Y$ verify $X \cup \{X\} = Y \cup \{Y\}$ then $X = Y$.
We can use a proof by contradiction (reductio ad absurbum) here.
Let us suppose $X \neq Y$ and $X \cup \{X\} = Y \cup \{Y\}$.
By definition, $X \in \{X\}$, so $X \in (X \cup \{X\})$. Because of the supposed equality we also have $X \in (Y \cup \{Y\})$. As $X\neq Y$ we know $X\notin\{Y\}$, so $X\in Y$.
Because of the symetry in $X,Y$, we also have $Y\in X$ (exactly the same demonstration after exchanging $X$ and $Y$.
This is in contradiction with the axiom of regularity because this axiom implies:

For every two sets, only one can be an element of the other

(quotation from the linked Wikipedia page).
That is enough to prove that $S(X) = S(Y) \implies X = Y$

It seems that the simplest approach is to use the von Neumann rank.  The rank goes up under the operation $S$.  Therefore $S$ is injective.

Thank you, I knew nothing, until now, about the von Neumann rank but surely it's simple to prove that $S$ is "injective" using it. However I'll try to prove using the way hinted by my book because, based on it, it's possible to prove without that. Thank you for your contribution
